# Parsing XML With LINQ Issue

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Sample XML:

```
<Response xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Result xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:string>18c03787-9222-4c9b-8f39-44c2b39c788e</a:string>
    <a:string>774d38d2-a350-4711-8674-b69404283448</a:string>
  </Result>
</Response>
```

When I attempt to parse this code I'm getting back null, i.e:

```
XNamespace temp = "http://tempuri.org/";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

All the following situations return null:

```
xdoc.Descendants(temp + "Result")
xdoc.Descendants();
xdoc.Element(temp + "Result");
```

What am I misunderstanding?

****** EDIT **********

Sorry for wasting everyone's time. 
It appears I was using http://www.tempuri.org instead of http://tempuri.org and incorrectly listed the proper one in my question.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Note that `Descendants()` wouldn't return `null` - it *could* return an empty sequence though. My guess is that the XML isn't actually what you think it is. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I *would* expect the last line to return `null`, but `xdoc.Root.Element(temp + "Result")` won't.

Comment: you are correct, `xdoc.Root.Element(temp + "Result")` returns the element, however this element doesn't contain any elements. (Also oddly enough xdoc.root.Desdcendants(temp + "Result") returns `{System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.GetDescendants}
    name: null
    self: false
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>.Current: null
    System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current: null`  How do I parse out the <a:string> values using a LINQ qyuery? I'm having great difficulty with this.

Comment: No, it really *will* contain elements. At this point, it would be a lot easier to help you if you would provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can pull out the  values in a couple of clear steps:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WaitForIt
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string thexml = @"<Response xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/""><Result xmlns:a=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""><a:string>18c03787-9222-4c9b-8f39-44c2b39c788e</a:string><a:string>774d38d2-a350-4711-8674-b69404283448</a:string></Result></Response>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(thexml);
        XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/";

        var result = doc.Descendants(ns + "Result");
        var resultStrings = result.Elements();

        foreach (var el in resultStrings)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(el.Value);
        }

        // output:
        // 18c03787-9222-4c9b-8f39-44c2b39c788e
        // 774d38d2-a350-4711-8674-b69404283448
     }        
   }
}
```